# How do I use data from a json file in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a json file with 6 "coins" to each user (which the user can change), I am trying to get this data saved in the json file and match it with another 6 coin pattern in order to check how many matches are made in total. The json file format is:

```
{"331971067788787733": [":Helicopter:", ":Skateboard1:", ":swords:", ":mace:", ":Helicopter:", ":Skateboard1:"]}
```

With each "coin" being a discord emoji.

The code for the user to save it is:

```
@client.command()
async def Shibaku1(ctx, coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6):

    with open('Shibaku1.json', 'r') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
    coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)] = (coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6)
    with open('Shibaku1.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(coins_data, f)
```

How do I extract the string value of each coin from the json file with the users 6 coins? in order to compare them with the main pattern to find the number of matches.

Comment: so if u print `coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]` , returns list?

Comment: `@client.command()
async def matches(ctx): 
  with open("Shibaku1.json") as f:
    usercoins = json.load(f)
    await ctx.send(usercoins)`

This is the code I have for it atm and it prints `{'331971067788787733': [':Helicopter:', ':Skateboard1:', ':swords:', ':mace:', ':mace:', ':mangosteen:', '1000']}`. @DjWalkzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So u can use for loop i list to compare the values, example given below :

```py
for coin in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
    if coin != new_coin:
        #do smthing
```

Comment: Wonderful that seemed to work, and also how would I display one of the values on the list?

Comment: You'd use `ctx.send(f"{coin}")` inside the block of the `coin != new_coin`

Comment: ah ok, one more question. The which I have written checks if the users coin matches the pattern and displays the number of matches. But for some reason this number repeats 6 times. Why is that?